# How to Hide or remove a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have declared a JLable as follows;

```
l = new JLabel("Hello");
l.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
panel.add(l);
```

Now, i want to hide or remove it. What should be the method i should call ?

i tried `l.removeAll();` <--- nothing hapend.

there's another one calle `remove(int)` which takes an int. But i am not sure what to pass as the parameter.

There's also something called `hide()`. but it's deprecated.

Comment: `l.removeAll()` won't work, you need to call the method on the item the label has been added to - in this case the panel.

Comment: `JLabel.setText("")` will make a label invisible so long as it has no icon.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> ```
> i tried l.removeAll(); <--- nothing hapend.
> ```

you need to call to `remove` on `JPanel` which the `JLabel` was added to :

```
panel.remove(l);

//after that you need to call this to revalidate and repaint the panel
panel.revalidate(); 
panel.repaint();
```

just to hide and not to remove call

```
l.setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

This may help you

Hiding Label

```
l.setVisible(false);
```

Removing from parent with passing the Label object as argument

```
panel.remove(l);
```

Remove all components

```
panel.removeAll();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try panel.remove(l);

panel.removeAll() should also work, but that also removes other components which may have been added to the pannel.

Answer (score 2):

you can try:

```
setVisible(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc of `hide()` tells `setVisible()` should be used instead. So try calling `setVisible(false)`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem in my project.

You should make sure about removing previous controls and refreshing the panel.

see this snippet code  :

```
panel.removeAll();  


panel.revalidate();
```

Hope This Helps U
All The Best :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the method `getContentPane()`. This way is possible to remove the element by the declaration name of the component.

```
private JFrame frame;
private JLabel label;
...

frame.getContentPane().remove(label);
```